# remove intersection between list elements

Tags: r, intervals

If I have list with 3 or more data frames. Each one has intervals then I wan to find if there is intersection between these intervals. If they intersect we need to remove the intersection. For example

```
d1<-cbind(st=c(1,4,6),ed=c(7,8,10)); d2<-cbind(st=c(4,8,17),ed=c(7,12,20)); d3<-cbind(st=c(1,8,25),ed=c(3,13,30))

l<-list(d1,d2,d3); l
```

I have plotted them for easy visualisation, black intervals from d1, blue d2 and red d3. The idea is to remove intersection regions, for example interval 1 in d1 and 1 in d2 and 1 in d3 intersects. I want the result to be

```
d2; st ed

    17 20

 d3; st ed
     13 13
     25 30
```

d1 will be removed because its intervals overlaps with other intervals in d2 and d3. The comparison should done at the same time which means to find the regions from all intervals in one data frame that overlap with other intervals from other data frame and remove them at the same time. 
I would appreciate any idea or suggestion

Edit: I want to separate interval find the new intervals that do not overlap with any other intervals (thank you Simon for your help to clarify this)but the important thing is to check all possible intersection before separating the intervals as some overlaps may disappear if the intervals are not compared before. The plot for the original intervals before separation

[image: intervals]

Comment: I can't figure out how the intervals in your plot would produce your expected output. Can you explain in more details what result you want to achieve. Do you want to find the intervals that do not overlap with any other intervals?

Comment: Exactly, I want to separate interval find the new intervals that do not overlap with any other intervals. The plot for the original intervals just to show how the expected result came.

Comment: Why don't you show the code that creates your plot?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find regions that are not overlapping between any regions, you can compute the coverage and extract all intervals where the coverage is exactly 1.

```
library(IRanges)

l <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
group start end
d1 1  7
d1 4  8
d1 6 10
d2 4  7
d2 8 12
d2 15 20
d3  1  3
d3  8 13
d3 25 30
")

ranges <- IRanges(start=l$start, end=l$end)
slice(coverage(ranges), lower=1, upper=1)
#> Views on a 30-length Rle subject
#> 
#> views:
#>     start end width
#> [1]    13  13     1 [1]
#> [2]    15  20     6 [1 1 1 1 1 1]
#> [3]    25  30     6 [1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

If you instead only want to check overlap with intervals that are not in the same group, you can, for each group, subtract the intervals not in the group from the intervals in the group.

```
lapply(unique(l$group), function(g) {
  r1 <- IRanges(start=l$start[l$group==g], end=l$end[l$group==g])
  r2 <- IRanges(start=l$start[l$group!=g], end=l$end[l$group!=g])
  as.data.frame(setdiff(r1, r2))
})
#> [[1]]
#> [1] start end   width
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   start end width
#> 1    15  20     6
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   start end width
#> 1    13  13     1
#> 2    25  30     6
```

**Old answer below**

You can use the [IRanges](http://IRanges) package in Bioconductor to reduce the set of intervals to only non-overlapping intervals.

```
l <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
group start end
d1 1  7
d1 4  8
d1 6 10
d2 4  7
d2 8 12
d2 15 20
d3  1  3
d3  8 13
d3 25 30
")

ranges <- IRanges(start=l$start, end=l$end, names=l$group)
reduced <- as.data.frame(reduce(ranges))
#>   start end width
#> 1     1  13    13
#> 2    15  20     6
#> 3    25  30     6
```

I am not sure how to keep the group names in the reduced result though. It might be possible using [GenomicRanges](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html%20GenomicRanges) instead, since they can include metadata as well.

Comment: Thank you Simon but that wouldn't help as the first interval (1,13) is the union of too many regions and those intervals should separated not find the union..

Comment: Ah, you're right. I've just updated my answer. Is this closer to what you want?

Comment: Thats great.. Thank you but how about the names (groups) in your updated code? how can I get them back? It is very important